# Make websites even working on IE compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, ie-compatibility-mode

This question may me seems out of bound but its needed in my case

I am under development of my site it works fine in all browsers except the IE compatibility mode. i was refer many sites and lot of answers in stack-overflow.

they all refer a single point as

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"> or EDGE
```

This will force the IE to skip the compatibility view but I need my site should stable  on IE compatibility mode also.

Hope i will get my answer here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to post this question to the Webmasters StackExchange forum instead: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need it to work in compatibility mode.**

Compatibility mode is designed for the *user's convenience* (i.e., not the programmer's) to make websites targeting earlier versions of IE *usable* in current versions.

If your webpage works properly in the current version, you don't need to make it work in compatibility view, and in fact, you *shouldn't* worry about making it work there. This isn't limited to IE's compatibility mode, it's generally true of *any* compatibility mode. You don't use it unless you have to, and the best pages don't have to.

The snippet you've already come across is the solution (there's a reason you see it all over the place). It tells IE that you properly support the latest version of the rendering engine, and therefore that it should use it to display your page. The user doesn't have to do anything special to make it work.

Comment: True, but what about people developing web apps that run on the local network. By default "display intranet sites in compatibility view" is turned on. Sys Admins have a pain disabling this and in my case don't care to anyway.